# Rails4: Saving a model from a different controller (with a form and POST)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, post, model, controller

I'm new with Ruby on Rails and this is my first question on SO, I hope someone will be able to help me.

I have a controller **Main** with a view **home**, in this view I have a form to create a new entry with a model **Mail**. My problem is that the entries in my DB are empty (I check with rails c, Mail.all), all the fields are set to nil (except the usuals like id). I could probably simplify my life by using a model and a controller with the same name but I'm pretty sure RoR should be able to handle this.

Model **Mail**:

```rb
class Mail < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Corresponding **schema.rb**:

```sql
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140217160636) do

  create_table "mails", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "type"
    t.boolean  "confirmed"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Controller **Main**:

```rb
class MainController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @mail = Mail.new
  end

  def create
    @mail = Mail.new(params[:main])
    if @mail.save
      redirect_to :root
    end
  end

end
```

Form from **_form.html.erb** shown in the view home through <%= render 'main/form' %> in application.html.erb:

```rb
<%= form_for @mail do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :address %>
  <%= f.select :type, [['Early adopter','early_adopter'],['Investisseur','investisor'],['Journaliste','journalist']] %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :confirmed, :value => false %>
  <%= f.submit("S'inscrire") %>
<% end %>
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

The debug line always shows:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
controller: main
action: home
```

Which doesn't help me much here.

Finally **routes.rb**:

```rb
LandingPage::Application.routes.draw do

  root 'main#home'
  resources :mails, controller: :main, :path => "/"

end
```

To sum up: everything almost works like a charm: the form is visible and functional, the post method re-routes to the root as wanted, a mail entry is created in the DB. My only problem is that the post info seems lost in the routing and the DB entry is empty.

In case it helps here is my install info.

**Gemfile**:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'i18n', '~> 0.6.9'
```

As I'm new to RoR I hope someone will just notice something I'm missing and explain it so that I can further my RoR education. Sorry if you get confused with Main/Mail, I'll try to differentiate my names better in the future.

**EDIT**:
I changed every instance of **mail** into **mail_info**, **mails** into **mail_infos** and did a successful **db:migrate**. I have the same problem, my **mail_infos** entries are empty (nil fields). So it's not about the name.

Comment: I don't think you can create a class called Mail, this is already the name of a builtin rails module. To test this, go to console and type 'Mail.new', see what type of object gets created

Comment: @Slicedpan IN that case, OP should have got error right?

Comment: yeah probably, maybe the file that contains the class definition for mail is not being loaded. I can't create a class called Mail in the console using rails 4, I get 'Mail is not a class' because it's already defined as a Module

Comment: Actually I just tried creating a file named mail.rb with just the class definition as above, and rails will not start at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use "type" name for column because it is used for single table inheritance.

Comment: This is the answer that finally solved my problem, though it is possible that the other changes were necessary as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)? Rails does not allow all values of your `Model` to be saved in DB. It will allow security vulnerabilities. So, you should use `strong parameters` which was called `attr_accessible` before RoR 4.

```
def create
  @mail = Mail.new(mail_params)
  if @mail.save
   redirect_to :root
  end
end

private

def mail_params
 params.require(:mail).permit(:address, :type, :confirmed)
end
```

Comment: I get:

Invalid single-table inheritance type: early_adopter is not a subclass of Mail

Comment: Try changing the name `Mail` to non-reserved word. As @Slicedpan commented, you should not use `Mail` which is a `module` in Rails.

Comment: I tried changing Mail to Mail_info, it did not solve my problem with my initial code.

I get the same "Invalid single-table inheritance type" error if I use the suggested code (even with the Mail -> Mail_info change).

Comment: Try changing the column name `type` to something else.